# Derivative of a (complicated) sum

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives

Given

$$
f(x)=e^{-ax}\ \sum_{k=0}^{r-1}\frac{(ax)^k}{k!}
$$

How do I show that
$$
f'(x)= -\frac{a^r}{(r-1)!}x^{r-1}e^{-ax}
$$

Thank you in advance!

Comment: There is a typo in the first expression. Also please include your attempts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the product rule,
$$
f'(x)=-ae^{-ax}S(x)+e^{-ax}S'(x),\qquad S(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{r-1}\frac{(ax)^k}{k!}.
$$
Now observe, using term-by-term differentiation, that
$$
S'(x)=a\sum_{k=0}^{r-2}\frac{(ax)^k}{k!}=a\left[S(x)-\frac{(ax)^{r-1}}{(r-1)!}\right].
$$
Consequently,
$$
f'(x)=-ae^{-ax}\frac{(ax)^{r-1}}{(r-1)!},
$$
which rearranges algebraically to your expression.

Comment: Thanks a lot. How do you get the first expression  $
S'(x)=a\sum_{k=0}^{r-2}\frac{(ax)^k}{k!}
$?

Comment: The derivative of $\frac{(ax)^k}{k!}$ is $a\cdot \frac{(ax)^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}$ after cancelling the $k$ from top and bottom, or in other words the $k^{th}$ term becomes the $(k-1)^{st}$ term.

Comment: Thank you for your quick and detailed help. Very much appreciated!

Comment: You have a good answer, but it's not good practice to answer questions without any context.

Answer (score 0):

It is:
$$f(x)=e^{-ax}\ \sum_{k=0}^{r-1}\frac{(ax)^k}{k!}=e^{-ax}\left(e^{ax}-\sum_{k=r}^{\infty} \frac{(ax)^k}{k!}\right)=1-e^{-ax}\sum_{k=r}^{\infty}\frac{(ax)^k}{k!} \Rightarrow \\
f'(x)=\color{red}{ae^{-ax}}\sum_{k=r}^{\infty}\frac{(ax)^k}{k!}-\color{red}{ae^{-ax}}\sum_{k=r}^{\infty}\frac{(ax)^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}=\color{red}{ae^{-ax}}\cdot \left(-\frac{(ax)^{r-1}}{(r-1)!}\right)=-\frac{a^r}{(r-1)!}x^{r-1}e^{-ax}.$$